# Bold round/first brackets

Tags: math-mode, equations, brackets

In the springer undergraduate lecture series, the books have very nice bold round/first brackets. Like the following

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

How do I get this type of bold round brackets in LaTeX?

Comment: It seems that the math font is mtpro2.

Comment: I beg to disagree about the adjective “nice”. 

Comment: Anyway, Springer uses its own Times based fonts.